# Linux audit logs - successful event with failure exit code

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, fedora, audit-logging

So let's say we have this event in the bottom of [page 76](https://books.google.ca/books?id=SY6IKocFwXIC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=type%3Dsyscall+syscall%3D5+success%3Dyes+exit%3D11&source=bl&ots=DbRl8Us7k3&sig=ACfU3U3eLDY_yOUjJ032iD_M0BrVuBhwyg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-_q-Do_rpAhUKj3IEHXVFD8EQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=type%3Dsyscall%20syscall%3D5%20success%3Dyes%20exit%3D11&f=false) where the `type=SYSCALL` `success=yes`and `exit=11`

I don't understand if this system call to the kernel has succeeded or not. The success field is set to `yes` so it seems the system call was successful but also the exit code was set to `11` which according to [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-bash-exit-status-set-exit-statusin-bash/) A non-zero (1-255) exit status indicates failure.

So is this considered a failure or not? How could it be a failure while success field is set to yes.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is an unsuccessful SYSCALL, the exit value will be negative which can be compared to the error table to find the type of error. For example, if there was an unsuccessful SYSCALL with exit code -1, then it means it is an EPREM (permission error) as stated in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h.

Whereas we there is a successful SYSCALL, the exit code can mean different things for different syscalls. For example, for an open SYSCALL the exit value would represent the FD of the file that was opened. For a read SYSCALL, the exit value would represent the bytes read.